# Unusal result from SQL query date

Tags: sql-server, date-arithmetic

I have the following query which should return 3 rows, however it returns none.  Yet if I run the second query I get the desired 3 rows.

Can anyone explain why the first one doesn't return the expected result set?  Even if I remove the conversion it still does the same.

3 rows should be 2019-06-18, 2019-06-06, 2019-06-17
This returns zero rows based on the current date (2019-06-10)

```sql
(
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Bill.InvoiceDate, 103) <= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, -21, GETDATE()), 103)  
    AND 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Bill.InvoiceDate, 103) >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, -41, GETDATE()), 103) 
)
```

This also produces zero rows

```
(
    Bill.InvoiceDate <= DATEADD(DAY, -21, GETDATE())
    AND 
    Bill.InvoiceDate >= DATEADD(DAY, -41, GETDATE())
)
```

This returns the 3 rows shown above

```sql
(
    Bill.InvoiceDate <= (GETDATE()-21)
    AND
    Bill.InvoiceDate >= (GETDATE()-41)
)
```

Based on Sami's comment, I've done the below and they come back with the same result

```sql
SELECT GETDATE()-21, DATEADD(DAY, -21, GETDATE())
```

```
| No column name          | No column name          |
|-------------------------|-------------------------|
| 2019-06-19 09:52:23.240 | 2019-06-19 09:52:23.240 |
```

Comment: Why would you compare DateTime columns as strings? Style103 is represented as `dd/mm/yyyy`, so that'll not compare the way you want. Why are you doing this? Your query comes down to `WHERE
 '18/06/2019' <= '19/06/2019'
 AND '18/06/2019' >= '30/05/2019'`, which will become a string comparison instead of a date comparison.

Comment: Why you're converting it to a varchar in the first place? Why not `Bill.InvoiceDate <= DATEADD(DAY, -21, GETDATE())`?

Comment: You're converting date/time values to a `varchar` and expecting them to continue to behave like a `date`. A `varchar` **is not** a `date`. As you're using the style code `103` that means your dates are in the format `dd/MM/yyyy`. For values like that, the *string* `'01/01/2019'` is **before** `'31/12/2000'` (yes, that's right, I said **before**). Strings are sorted by each character left to right. `'3'` > `'0'` so `'31/12/2000'` is *after* `'01/01/2019'`. Don't convert your values to a `varchar`, and likely this issue doesn't exist.

Comment: it does the same even without the convert in there

Comment: What's the results of `SELECT GETDATE()-21, DATEADD(DAY, -21, GETDATE())`?

Comment: @Sami they are the same '2019-06-19 09:52:23.240' and '2019-06-19 09:52:23.240'

Comment: @Neo Ithink you understand that the 3rd and 4th queries are the same, there is issue as we can see from what you provide, unless there is something you didn't provide. I suggest you provide table definition + sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the problem with query 1 is that you are comparing strings.

Let's see what the 3 dates you mention look like when `convert`ed to `nvarchar(10)` in style `103`:

```
06/06/2019 
17/06/2019 
18/06/2019
```

and your `WHERE` clause is essentially:

```
database_value <= '19/06/2019'
and
database_value >= '30/05/2019'
```

Notice that as a string, '30/05/2019' begins with '3', and is thus larger in string comparison than any of the 3 values you mention which begin with either a '1' or '0'.

Since you really want date comparison, the second query is right.

As an additional notice, I really doubt that the first query "does the same" if you remove `convert`. When comparing a string to a date, the datatype precedence dictates that the string gets automatically converted to date.

Comment: it does the same even without the convert in there